# studying the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {3^n}{n^32^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> I'm studying the convergence of the series
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {3^n}{n^32^n}$$

- $\frac {3^n}{n^32^n}>0, \forall n \ge 1$
- $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac {3^n}{n^32^n}$ should be $0$ .

In another post I've seen that $\frac {3^n}{n^3}>2^n \rightarrow \frac {3^n}{n^32^n}>1 \rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac {3^n}{n^32^n} \ne 0$ and the given serie diverges.
But I could proof that $\frac {3^n}{n^3}>2^n $ ?

Comment: Just evaluate the limit when $n\to\infty$ of the terms of your series.

Comment: The same suggestion given in your previous question applies here, too. Trivially divergent.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm afraid you didn't understand my question...please focus on the questions and on the difficulties that someone could have rather than assuming that annoying know-it-all tone...and don't delete your answers as you did in another post, please

Comment: Your question is perfectly clear as it is perfectly obvious. Such series is divergent, blatantly. My previous friendly suggestion was really a friendly suggestion: what do you plan to achieve by letting others overcome the small technical difficulties you are supposed to overcome, for the benefit of your own understanding and mathematical growth? Of course, you are free to ask whatever you like, just like other users are free to vote for closing due to lack of context/attempts.

Answer (score 1):

By ratio test we get $$\frac { { a }_{ n+1 } }{ { a }_{ n } } =\frac { \frac { { 3 }^{ n+1 } }{ { \left( n+1 \right)  }^{ 3 }{ 2 }^{ n+1 } }  }{ \frac { { 3 }^{ n } }{ { n }^{ 3 }{ 2 }^{ n } }  } =\frac { 3 }{ 2 } { \left( 1-\frac { 1 }{ n+1 }  \right)  }^{ 3 }\quad \overset { n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \longrightarrow  } \frac { 3 }{ 2 } >1$$

Answer (score 0):

Considering Cauchy root test we obtain: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1\over n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1.5}{(n)^\frac{3}{n}}=1.5>1$$ which implies on divergence of the corresponding series.

Answer (score 0):

Define 
$$a_n=\frac{3^n}{n^32^n}$$

If $n\ge 10$,
$$\frac{(n+1)^3}{n^3}=\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)^3\le1.1^3<\frac32$$

Since 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac32\cdot\frac{n^3}{(n+1)^3}$$
the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is *increasing* for $n\ge 10$. Since its terms are positive, their sum will hardly converge.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution applying the induction to $\frac {3^n}{n^3}>2^n$

- $P(1)$ is evidently true
- let's suppose $P(n)$ true
- $2^{n+1}=2^n2<\frac {3^n}{n^3}2<\frac {3^n}{n^3}3<\frac {3^n}{(n+1)^3}3 =\frac {3^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3} \rightarrow P(n+1) $ true

Comment: It should read $(n+1)^3$ in the denominator.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek I edited the text